# append list with dictionary type in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I tried add dict type data in existed list, but when I try with just append it showed me None.

Here is what I tried:

```
    data = ast.literal_eval(''.join(ptdata['partnerlist']))
    for add in partner:
        adata = add
    invite_list = data.append(adata)
```

and partner data is same as below:

```
[{'phn':'111-1111-1111'}]
```

It is code for taking out data from DB and adding data with current DB data.
I hope to know availability of list appending dict type and would you advice me an way of fixing it.

Thanks.

Comment: `append()` returns `None` it mutates the list you call it from so it has no return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `data.append()` returns `None`. The reason for this is it just modify's the object that it appends to. Just do this:

```
invite_list = data
invite_list.append(adata)
```